# Getting the value of a form input

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there was a way to get the value of a form input value without having to use a event listener.

Heres the portion of the code related to that:

```
<form class="searchBar" id="form">
     <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
     <button type="submit" id="submit">
     <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="#666666" d="M9.5,3A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 16,9.5C16,11.11 15.41,12.59 14.44,13.73L14.71,14H15.5L20.5,19L19,20.5L14,15.5V14.71L13.73,14.44C12.59,15.41 11.11,16 9.5,16A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 3,9.5A6.5,6.5 0 0,1 9.5,3M9.5,5C7,5 5,7 5,9.5C5,12 7,14 9.5,14C12,14 14,12 14,9.5C14,7 12,5 9.5,5Z" />
    </svg>
</form>
```

Heres what I've tried so far:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const search = document.getElementById('search');

let query;

/*function submitted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(search.value)
    search.value = "";
}
form.addEventListener('submit', submitted);*/

console.log(search.value)
```

The commented out code correctly displayed the search value, but this used the event listener.

I wanted to assign the search value to the `query`. When I commented out the block of code, nothing was displayed in the console after I typed in an input.

Wondering how to assign value of `search.value` to `query`.

Comment: You are going to have to use some sort of event listener, there is no magic mapping of the value to a variable. What are you really trying to do? Do you want to use oninput on the textbox itself instead of a form?

Comment: You can use it without event listener initially on load if there is default value loaded inside the input. If not you should use keyup/input/submit/etc... event

Comment: Is your goal to "bind" the user input with `query` variable? Maybe you could try to listen some event on the input

Comment: @epascarello I was thinking about getting the query input and then using that value to request to an api. Like depending on the query input, the api would return something different.

Comment: @damian ye pretty much

Comment: So you need to use an event like I said. `oninput` on the textbox is probably what you want. Maybe form submit is actually correct. Seems like you are over thinking this before you code something. If you are going to call an api, you need to know when the variable is updated so you will need to use an event....

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get the value without submit event. If yes, Please try to do like this.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const search = document.getElementById('search');

let query;

search.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  query = event.target.value;
});
```

Comment: um i'm not really sure how to say it. But like lets say you type something into the search bar (the form). Like "hello", then the query should be assigned "hello"